# What is the %||% operator (used in ggplot2) and where is it defined?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am going through some of the `ggplot2` code and I stumbled over (well actually the compiler stumbled over it) the `%||%` operator. I imagine it is some kind of an "logical-or" function, seemingly related to parameters, but somehow it is not defined in my environment. I have included all the dependencies that I think `ggplot2` has (`plyr,scales,reshape2,digest,MASS,gtable`) with a `library` statement but it did not help.

`?%||%` and `??%||%` from R-studio didn't help, neither did using the SO search and Google and even Bing. I actually think most search services just refuse to search for such things, which makes finding these operators really difficult.

Not really sure where to look now, short of bugging the package authors who have far better things to do with their time - especially these package authors.

So where is it, and where should/could I have looked to find it? I really want to be self-sufficient about these kind of things.

Comment: Maybe it's this one http://www.inside-r.org/node/382731 or this one http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/falsy/docs/or? Probably the first since it's from a package created by Hadley.

Comment: I would upvote that as an answer if you post it. Looking in "inside-r" was something I had not thought about.

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this. Any ideas? Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: I didn't know the operator as well, which was why I decided to post as a comment. And no, I don't know why anyone would downvote it. Wasn't me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial approach was good, one additional trick would be to add backticks to your query:

```
R> ?`%||%`
```

Which brings up the help page for null-default from [purrr](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/blob/master/man/null-default.Rd) that describes it as "This infix function makes it easy to replace NULLs with a default value"

In use:

```
R> 1 %||% 2
[1] 1
R> NULL %||% 2
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the definition here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/utilities.r#L10-L12

```
"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}
```

It's a very nice short cut to add. You'll find it in many of Hadley's packages.

Comment: This of course is what is really happening, but I don't see how I could have found it without reading a lot more code.

Comment: Btw loved your blog about extending ggplot2